# Jenkins EC2 plugin cant launch windows slave (Unexpected EOF)

Tags: windows, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Recently i started to create my AWS environment for Windows 2008 slaves.

I have configured my AMI (2008 x64) with:

- Jenkins user under Administrators group
- Windows Firewall off. (I reach the instance using telnet to 445 and 5985 ports)
- WinRM HTTP configuration:

  winrm quickconfig

  winrm set winrm/config/service/Auth @{Basic="true"}

  winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}

  winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="1024"}

This is the Jenkins log:

```
WinRM service responded. Waiting for WinRM service to stabilize on Windows slave (i-089160ce7ccb480fb)
WinRM should now be ok on Windows slave (i-089160ce7ccb480fb)
Connected with WinRM.
Creating tmp directory if it does not exist
slave.jar sent remotely. Bootstrapping it
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Slave.jar version: 2.60
This is a Windows agent
ERROR: Connection terminated
Ouch:
hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException: java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF
    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:303)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:847)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:92)
    at ......remote call to Windows slave (i-089160ce7ccb480fb)(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1416)
    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:780)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:536)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:381)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.win.EC2WindowsLauncher.launch(EC2WindowsLauncher.java:70)
    at hudson.plugins.ec2.EC2ComputerLauncher.launch(EC2ComputerLauncher.java:122)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:253)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:99)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:99)
    at hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
```

UPDATE: The problem is the java x64. With a Windows x64 with a installed java x32 it works, very slow, but works.

I need help, this is very important for my work.
Thanks!